# what's wrong with this $_POST and sql code?

Tags: php, sql

The following code runs fine, but it doesn't update the mysql database.

The sql query isn't the problem because I commented out the if statement and the MySQL database updates fine. It has to do with the $_POST array. I have a feeling when I put in the $row["id"] into the $_POST array, it's not going in nicely.

```
if (isset($_POST["
         {$row["id"]}
         "]) && !empty($_POST["
                      {$row["id"]}
                      "])){
  print_r($_POST);
 $food_id = $_POST[$row["id"]];



 $query = "INSERT INTO `users_foods`
VALUES('','1','7','','','','')";

//$_SESSION['user_id']

   $query_run = mysql_query($query);

}
```

Comment: Why would you not just insert the row_id directly?  `isset($_POST[$row['id']])`  This question is tough to answer without knowing the contents of $row['id'] and how it is initialized.

Comment: you probably get some massive syntax errors...

Comment: Have you checked the client side code that's posting the data to ensure it's working correctly?

Comment: give HTML Code of the row["id"] input tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{$row["id"]}
```

should be

```
{$row['id']}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with the quotes

`isset($_POST["{$row["id"]}"]` is wrong, you probably want:

- `isset($_POST[$row["id"]]` or
- `isset($_POST[{$row["id"]}]` or
- `isset($_POST["{$row[\"id\"]}"]` (use the scape to mark the quotes are part of the string)

But I guess you are looking for the first one

Answer (score 0):

the quotes in the if statement... try using

```
    $_POST[row["id"]];
```

Comment: still didn't post not sure why